# Realm IList not updating UWP ListView

Tags: list, uwp, realm

I am just converting and app from C#/WPF to C#/UWP (Windows 10) and it seems that IList does not update the UWP ListView.
So first question - should it ?
and if not then how should I bind the IList property to ensure the ListView will update if items are added or removed?
Maybe some more context - new items are getting created on a background thread - and the exact same method/code seems to work fine with C#/WPF.

```xml
<ListView x:Name="siteListView"  SelectionChanged="SiteListView_SelectionChanged" 
                             DataContext="{x:Bind _this}" 
ItemsSource="{x:Bind Customer.items, Mode=OneWay}"  >
```

---

```cs
public class Customer : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string address { get; set; }

    public string contact { get; set; }

    public float complianceScore { get; set; }
    public string completionStatus { get; set; }

    public IList<Site> sites { get; }
}
```

Comment: Collection change notifications were observed by INotifyCollectionChanged interface. If the given IList instance will also implement that interface then it should update the view, otherwise not

Comment: Yes I know that - but I don't know if IList does implement the interface, nor do I know how to find that out.  I do know it works under WPF but that might be a different interface.  So if you know whether it does implement the interface and have used it yourself let me know - it could be a bug in the version I am using or it could be UWP is not supported for some reason.

Comment: I did not even work with Realm before. But generally I would never use the ORM classes at the UI level. The ORM classes are only for persisting data (**S**ingle **R**esponsibility **P**rinciple). So I never had to care about if the real implementer on the ORM class also implements an interface the UI relys on

Comment: FYI [Uncle Bob: Objects and Data Structures](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2019/06/16/ObjectsAndDataStructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems Realm IList does not implement the IList interface because of some conflicts with Android and as a result UWP bindings won't work.  BUT I found a relatively simple solution. https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1575

```
public partial class SimpleList : ContentPage
    {

        ObservableCollection<Item> observableItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        IRealmCollection<Item> rawItems;

        public class SimpleList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            rawItems = realm.All<Item>().AsRealmCollection();

            foreach (Item item in rawItems)
            {
                observableItems.Add(item);
            }

            rawItems.SubscribeForNotifications((sender, changes, error) =>
            {
                if (changes != null)
                {
                    foreach (int i in changes.DeletedIndices)
                    {
                        observableItems.RemoveAt(i);
                    }

                    foreach (int i in changes.InsertedIndices)
                    {
                        observableItems.Insert(i, rawItems[i]);
                    }
                    foreach (int i in changes.ModifiedIndices)
                    {
                        observableItems.RemoveAt(i);
                        observableItems.Insert(i, rawItems[i]);
                    }

                }

                if (error != null)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle Exceptions
                }


            });

            MyListView.ItemsSource = observableItems;

        }

        async void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // DO Stuff

            // Deselect Item
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }

    }
```